# jQuery if div id has class, hide other div

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to hide an img with an id of "offer" if li id "print" has class frame3. frame3 is a class that's added to the front slide on a carousel I'm working on. I seem to have gotten it working if i use only the class. However, when I combine it with the ID, no dice. Appreciate any help...thanks much!

Here's what I'm working with.

Markup:

```
 <div class="main-container" style="position:relative;">
        <ul id="slider">
            <li><img src="images/img-1.png"><span><img src="images/slide-1-text.png"></span></li>
            <li><img src="images/img-2.png"><span><img src="images/slide-2-text.png"></span></li>
            <li><img src="images/img-3.png"><span><img src="images/slide-3-text.png"></span></li>
            <li><img src="images/img-4.png"><span><img src="images/slide-4-text.png"></span></li>
            <li><img src="images/img-5.png"><span><img src="images/slide-5-text.png"></span></li>
            <li><img src="images/img-6.png"><span><img src="images/slide-6-text.png"></span></li>
            <li><img src="images/img-7.png"><span><img src="images/slide-7-text.png"></span></li>
            <li><img src="images/img-8.png"><span><img src="images/slide-8-text.png"></span></li>
            <li><img src="images/img-9.png"><span><img src="images/slide-9-text.png"></span></li>
            <li><img src="images/img-10.png"><span><img src="images/slide-10-text.png"></span></li>
            <li><img src="images/img-11.png"><span><img src="images/slide-11-text.png"></span></li>
            <li><img src="images/img-12.png"><span><img src="images/slide-12-text.png"></span></li>
            <li id="print" class="frame3"><img src="images/US_img-13-preview.png"><span><a class="button" rel="print" href="#">Print</a></span></li>
        </ul>

        <img id="prev" src="images/previous.png" onclick="slider_previous()"/> 
        <img id="next" src="images/next.png" onclick="slider_next()"/> 
        <img src="images/offer.png" id="offer" onclick="slider_goto(13); return false"/> 
    </div>
```

jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    if($("#print").hasClass("frame3") == true) {
        $("#offer").hide();
    }    
 });
```

Comment: Side note: You don't need this `== true`.

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/o445nmq2/

Comment: It's working already, but you need just this: `$('#offer').toggle($('#print').hasClass('frame3'));`

Comment: Do you get any errors on the browser console? Are you loading the `jQuery` library?

Comment: thanks for the quick responses.  yes, jquery is loading and i'm not getting any console errors. going to try MelanciaUK's suggestion now.

Comment: thanks for the help everyone. it was a conflict with another js file. I was able to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you have requested an answer in jQuery, but for the sake of completeness, I thought I would write out the equivalent answer in Javascript.

You can identify the 2 DOM nodes you're working with:

```
var printListItem = document.getElementById('print');
var offerImage = document.getElementById('offer');
```

Then you can execute a simple `if, then` statement:

```
if (printListItem.className === 'frame3') {
offerImage.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Putting the whole thing together:

```
function hideOfferImage() {
    var printListItem = document.getElementById('print');
    var offerImage = document.getElementById('offer');
    if (printListItem.className === 'frame3') {
    offerImage.style.display = 'none';
    }

window.onload = hideOfferImage();
```